# highcharts legend entries not clickable in firefox

Tags: highcharts

I have several highcharts graphs set up and have recently noticed that I'm unable to click on legend entries to show/hide their associated series in Firefox. This works fine in Chrome and Safari so it seems like this is a browser-related issue.

I've noticed that the highcharts demoes do not have this problem, so it must be something I'm doing in my implementation but I'm having a very difficult time figuring it out. What is it that Firefox does differently that could cause this sort of problem with highcharts?

Point of interest: if I set the chart's useHtml parameter to true, the legend entries become clickable. This is not a solution however because it breaks a bunch of other stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the simplest reproducible example.

Comment: Please reproduce your example in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce this problem in jsfiddle. I assume this means there's some sort of problem with the container in which I'm drawing the graph. If anything comes to mind that could be an issue please let me know otherwise I'll post the solution here when I find it.

Comment: It's worth noting that this can be fixed by setting legend.useHTML = true, but that causes another problem where the chart legend fails to clear old items when it redraws, so you end up with legend entries stacked on top of old legend entries.

Comment: Have you the newest highcharts (3.0.1 ? )

Comment: Yes, we are using 3.0.1. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem, which happened for me in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but not in IE9.

I found out the problem is CSS related. My page has 2 "boxes"; left and right. My Vaadin pie chart is sitting on the right box. On the left box I have a html `<H1>` tag that has width overflow to the right box (width: 900px) which covers part of the pie chart. As a result some rectangular area is not clickable. This can easily be fixed by using the Firefox Firebug tool to inspect the CSS. I hope this saves you the hours I spent to install the latest vaadin chart library; debug the codes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if this was our problem since I've switched projects since making this post, but I'm glad you sorted it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in which points in line graphs were not clickable in Firefox (but they were clickable in Chrome). Turned out that Firefox places the dataLabels on top of the graph points.

Solved it with:

```
     plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        zIndex: 2
```

See also: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels